# How to write a function in coffeescript that wraps around another function?

Tags: coffeescript

Suppose I want to wrap an arbitrary function to add something like logging (or anything else). The wrapper should be generic and work for any `f` which can be called with any kind of parameters.

```
createWrapper= (f) ->
   wrapper= -> 
     # do the logging or whatever I want before I call the original
     result= ???
     # do whatever after the original function call
     result
```

Usage would be:

```
g=createWrapper(f)
```

now `g` should be called in any way `f` would be called, like

```
result = g(1,2,3)
```

should return the same as

```
result = f(1,2,3)
```

And now I can use `g` wherever I would use `f` but it calls my wrapper function.

My question is: how should I call `f` to get the result?

Comment: My guess is: ```f.apply @,arguments```

Comment: Your guess is correct :). This is a good read on JS decorator functions (translating it to CS should be no problem): https://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2013/01/function_and_method_decorators.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

```
f.apply @, arguments
```

Therefore the wrapper looks like

```
createWrapper= (f) ->
   -> 
     # do the logging or whatever I want before I call the original
     result= f.apply @, arguments
     # do whatever after the original function call
     result
```

or if you don't want to do anything after the call

```
createWrapper= (f) ->
   -> 
     # do the logging or whatever I want before I call the original
     f.apply @, arguments
```

or if you want to be a bit more explicit, you can use a [splat](http://coffeescript.org/#splats).
This has the advantage that the arguments are a list and you can apply
list operations on the arguments.

```
createWrapper= (f) ->
   (args...) -> 
     # do the logging or whatever I want before I call the original
     result= f.apply @, args
     # do whatever after the original function call
     result
```

Here is some test [code](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3acreateWrapper%3D%20%28f%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%28args...%29%20-%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20do%20the%20logging%20or%20whatever%20I%20want%20before%20I%20call%20the%20original%0A%20%20%20%20%20result%3D%20f.apply%20%40%2C%20args%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20do%20whatever%20after%20the%20original%20function%20call%0A%20%20%20%20%20result%0A%0Aclass%20cl%0A%20%20%20i%3A%2010%0A%20%20%20f%3A%20%28x%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20x%20%2B%20%40i%0A%20%20%20getf%3A%20%28x%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%28x%29%3D%3E%40f%28x%29%0A%0Ac%20%3Dnew%20cl%0Af1%20%3D%20c.getf%28%29%0Ag1%20%3D%20createWrapper%28f1%29%0Aif%20f1%281%29!%3Dg1%281%29%0A%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error%28%22failed%20f1%20%23%7Bf1%201%7D%20!%3D%20%23%7Bg1%201%7D%22%29%0A%0Af2%20%3D%20%28x%29%20-%3E%20x%2B20%0Ag2%20%3D%20createWrapper%28f2%29%0Aif%20f2%281%29!%3Dg2%281%29%0A%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error%28%22failed%20f2%20%23%7Bf2%201%7D%20!%3D%20%23%7Bg2%201%7D%22%29%0A%0A%0Af3%20%3D%20%28args...%29%20-%3E%20%22%23%7Bargs%7D%22%0Ag3%20%3D%20createWrapper%28f3%29%0Aif%20f3%281%2C2%2C3%29!%3Dg3%281%2C2%2C3%29%0A%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error%28%22failed%20f3%20%23%7Bf3%201%2C2%2C3%7D%20!%3D%20%23%7Bg3%201%2C2%2C3%7D%22%29%0A%0Af4%20%3D%20-%3E%20arguments%5B0%5D%0Ag4%20%3D%20createWrapper%28f4%29%0Aif%20f4%281%29!%3Dg4%281%29%0A%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error%28%22failed%20f4%20%23%7Bf4%201%7D%20!%3D%20%23%7Bg4%201%7D%22%29%0A%0Af5%20%3D%20c.f%0Ag5%20%3D%20createWrapper%28f5%29%0Aif%20f5.apply%28c%2C%5B1%5D%29!%3Dg5.apply%28c%2C%5B1%5D%29%0A%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error%28%22failed%20f5%20%23%7Bf5.apply%20c%2C%5B1%5D%7D%201%3D%20%23%7Bg5.apply%20c%2C%5B1%5D%7D%22%29%0A%0Aalert%28%22%22%22%0AEverything%20is%20OK%3A%0A%20%20%20f1%20%23%7Bf1%201%7D%20%3D%3D%20%23%7Bg1%201%7D%20%0A%20%20%20f2%20%23%7Bf2%201%7D%20%3D%3D%20%23%7Bg2%201%7D%20%0A%20%20%20f3%20%23%7Bf3%201%2C2%2C3%7D%20%3D%3D%20%23%7Bg3%201%2C2%2C3%7D%20%0A%20%20%20f4%20%23%7Bf4%201%7D%20%3D%3D%20%23%7Bg4%201%7D%20%0A%20%20%20f5%20%23%7Bf5.apply%20c%2C%5B1%5D%7D%20%3D%3D%20%23%7Bg5.apply%20c%2C%5B1%5D%7D%20%0A%22%22%22%29%0A):

```
createWrapper= (f) ->
   (args...) -> 
     # do the logging or whatever I want before I call the original
     result= f.apply @, args
     # do whatever after the original function call
     result

class cl
   i: 10
   f: (x) ->
     x + @i
   getf: (x) ->
     (x)=>@f(x)

c =new cl
f1 = c.getf()
g1 = createWrapper(f1)
if f1(1)!=g1(1)
   throw new Error("failed f1 #{f1 1} != #{g1 1}")

f2 = (x) -> x+20
g2 = createWrapper(f2)
if f2(1)!=g2(1)
   throw new Error("failed f2 #{f2 1} != #{g2 1}")


f3 = (args...) -> "#{args}"
g3 = createWrapper(f3)
if f3(1,2,3)!=g3(1,2,3)
   throw new Error("failed f3 #{f3 1,2,3} != #{g3 1,2,3}")

f4 = -> arguments[0]
g4 = createWrapper(f4)
if f4(1)!=g4(1)
   throw new Error("failed f4 #{f4 1} != #{g4 1}")

f5 = c.f
g5 = createWrapper(f5)
if f5.apply(c,[1])!=g5.apply(c,[1])
   throw new Error("failed f5 #{f5.apply c,[1]} 1= #{g5.apply c,[1]}")

alert("""
Everything is OK:
   f1 #{f1 1} == #{g1 1} 
   f2 #{f2 1} == #{g2 1} 
   f3 #{f3 1,2,3} == #{g3 1,2,3} 
   f4 #{f4 1} == #{g4 1} 
   f5 #{f5.apply c,[1]} == #{g5.apply c,[1]} 
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run f()

```
createWrapper = (f) ->
  wrapper= -> 
    # do the logging or whatever I want before I call the original
    result= f()
    # do whatever after the original function call
    result
```

Comment: I want the parameters that are passed down to f -- I should have made my question clearer...